# iOS development using C# APIs

Tags: c#, .net, ios, wcf, json

I am looking to get into doing some iOS development for a nice addition to a project i am running.

The main project is currently written in C# and is mainly asp.net with a few windows services. 
I would like to incorporate this to be able to develop a basic iPhone app as a proof of concept.

From what i have read and understand, its generally best practice to use JSON as a communication medium for iOS.

I am thinking about using WCF to create the API methods so the iOS app can connect to these services to get the data.

Are there any nice tutorials to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at:

[Developing RESTful iOS Apps with RestKit](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/)

Comment: that is the way i use, however RestKit some issues with mappings for OData services.
I will also consider using xml service in iOS as it is seems to be well supported by using Core Data

Answer (score 2):

I do this all the time.  WCF Data Services (OData) are the way to go.  With OData services, you can specify that you want JSON response by passing (Accept - Application/JSON) in the HTTP Header and OData will return JSON to you.

I have used several libraries for getting OData (which are REST services) from iOS. Microsoft's iOS OData implementation is pretty lame.  RESTKit does a really good job for what it handles, but is really painful if you have to do something that it doesn't.  I have also used ASI - it is much more flexible than RESTKit, but is not without problems.  I ended up writing my own and it suits me just fine.

For a beginner, I would recommend using ASI over RESTKit. RESTKit, while doing a lot of the heavy lifting for you, takes a bit to get working right.

There are two things that are not standard when receiving JSON responses from OData.
1.  All responses are captured in a JSONDictionary with the key of "D".
2.  Dates are serialized to the JSON standard (number of seconds since 1970), but they are placed in a string like so: /Date(1212353), so you will have to parse out  the Date() part of the string before you can use it.

RESTKit doesn't handle either one of these issues natively, so you will have to deal with them if you choose that route.  Personally, I would go the ASI route until you learn enough to write your own.

I am considering open sourcing my solution - if I do, I will update this response with the link to it.

---UPDATE----

Just to be clear - if your server side system uses WCF Data Services, otherwise known as OData, then with minor tweaking, RESTKit plays nice with it.  If your services are traditional WCF Services (i.e. SOAP Binding), then you will not be able to get JSON out of them because they are bound to the SOAP protocol (Unless you create a custom Behavior to translate it - which I wouldn't do).  It all depends on what your services do in essence.  If your services are typically data exposure/manipulation (i.e. addCustomer), then you should expose them as OData.  If they are truly operations, then you should maybe consider exposing them as actions from a MVC site.  Either of them can get you REST services using your existing infrastructure and platform.

Comment: Sounds like you know what you are talking about.  I am going to investigate RESTKit.  But basically what you are saying is that it plays nice with WCF services

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Objective-C to develop the iPhone app, I'm not sure WCF is the best web service technology to use on the server. Check out [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net/) to create a RESTful service.

Comment: Although I said Objective-C, I actually mean the iOS SDK, Cocoa Touch, Objective-C etc. You can still use the aforementioned RestKit to consume the web service.

Comment: I completely disagree with this statement.  I have been working on a team that does this exclusively and we have loved this implementation for more than an year..

Comment: @JosephDeCarlo WCF or OData? From my understanding there are wrinkles with standard WCF services.

Comment: OData is a part of WCF - so Yes.  "Traditional" WCF Services are typically implemented using SOAP and I am sure that is quite painful to consume in iOS.  However, even traditional WCF services support other protocols.

Comment: Thanks @JosephDeCarlo for clarifying your comment. I offered an opinion to an alternative solution as opposed to WCF services, I did not say it was not worth trying WCF Services or WCF Data Services, just that 'I'm not sure WCF is the best web service technology to use'. Some people might struggle with the WCF issues you've outlined, especially traditional WCF services, so I suggested a free, open source REST alternative that might be worth a try.

Comment: Fair enough. Most don't realize the power of OData. If you're are not familiar with it and you're already on .NET, you should really take a look at it. It only takes few minutes to create all your services for a RDMS. You can also create services for databases like Mongo, they just take a little more work. There's no need to code operations like "customersWithAnOutstandingBalance" because you can query the service to get that information. I have yet to see an service architecture with such power with so little effort. ServiceStack looks promising for operation style services though.

Answer (score 0):

Refer following link:

http://www.kotancode.com/2011/04/26/backing-your-ios-app-with-wcf-json-web-services/

It has included comprehensive code samples as well.